# How to use bash to filter csv by column value and remove duplicates based on multiple columns

Tags: bash, csv, awk

I'm trying to filter my CSV by the value of one column, and then remove duplicate rows based on the values of 2 columns. For the sake of simplicity, here's an example. I would like to remove duplicate rows based on columns ID1, ID2 and Year. I would also like to filter my results by only pulling back rows with "3" in the VALUE column.

```
ID1,ID2,YEAR,LAT,LON,VALUE  
A,B,2016,123,456,3  
A,B,2016,133,466,3  
A,B,2016,122,446,3  
C,D,2015,223,456,3  
C,D,2015,241,455,3  
A,B,2016,123,456,2  
A,B,2016,133,466,2  
A,B,2016,122,446,2  
C,D,2015,223,456,2  
C,D,2015,241,455,2
```

RESULT:

```
ID1,ID2,YEAR,LAT,LON,VALUE  
A,B,2016,123,456,3  
C,D,2015,223,456,3
```

Comment: Either your description is wrong or your example is wrong as your description says your input is a CSV but your example contains no Commas. Fix your question to be accurate.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk` that uses an associative array with key as composite value commprising `$1,$2,$3`:

```
awk -F, '$NF==3 && !seen[$1,$2,$3]++' file.csv
ID1,ID2,YEAR,LAT,LON,VALUE
A,B,2016,123,456,3
C,D,2015,223,456,3
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the response @anubhava! So that's the script I've been using, which does remove some of the duplicates, but I'm still seeing some it hasn't resolved in the CSV. It seems to work fine when I convert the csv to txt before running it though, so I figured I'd throw this question out there to try and identify why.

Comment: Since your edited input file is comma separated, you just needed to have `-F,` in awk command. Try my updated command now.

Answer (score 1):

this solution assumes the same as was metioned above, but in more expanded version.
Both `awk` solutions won't work if there is `,` in the values. Then insted of that you could use `csvtool` to separate values.

```
cat file1 |  awk -F, ' $NF==3 {unq[$1,$2,$3]=$0}  END{for (i in unq){print unq[i] }}'
```